# what is the PHPMyAdmin db_user, and where can I find it?

Tags: php, sql, cpanel, host

I am trying to connect my PHP code with my own external server (purchased from go daddy) - but i have run into a few problems and I hope that someone can please help.

I have purchased a package from go daddy and have tried to set a db_user for the PHPMyAdmin - however, this has not worked. So i reset everything in relation to db_user, and I still cannot connect. So what is the db_user? And where can I find it (i.e. CPanel, PHPMyAdmin)?

Any help is highly appreciated! I have tried so many different things but have reached a bottleneck! Thanks

This is what the browser gives me, as follows:[image]

This is the code so far:

[image]

And this is what I am trying to achieve:

[image]

Comment: Hi, yeah I have PHPMyAdmin access - and when I assign a user it doesn't seem to want to connect - could it be XAMPP by any chance messing things up?

Comment: Yeah I can see the MySQL® Databases :)

Comment: Yeah I have done - I have also assigned the db_password to the user

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/91964/discussion-between-subin-thomas-and-r-jones).

Answer (score 0):

db_ user is Means Database user... go to mysql database in cpanel there you will find your database click on it you will find the user...

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. I have done this previously, created a user, created a password - but when I input it into the code above - it doesn't seem to work. Any suggestions? Could it be XAMPP by any chance?

Answer (score 0):

I think you are created user, but not given permission for the user on the db.

[image: Add user to DB]

This will be required to do, to grant privileges for user on the DB.

Answer (score 0):

Many hosting providers do not allow external connections; it's likely that your phpMyAdmin instance is located on their internal network (which is why it's working) but your application is getting rejected because it's on an external IP address. In this case, you'll need to ask your host for help connecting to your database.